# Is there any correlation between eigen functions and eigen vectors of an LTI system?

Tags: control-system, math, lti-system

Eigen functions are the origin for Laplace transform while eigen vectors is for state space representation.Can we relate the eigen concept in these two?

The complex exponential functions, are eigen functions of any LTI system. Also there are infinitely many such  linearly independent eigen functions.Then why do we say a second order LTI system has only 2 eigen values/vectors?" 
Is it like eigen functions of LTI and eigen vectors of LTI should not be correlated?

Comment: Isn't it the case that it still has an infinite number but 2 have to be stable? Maybe you can substantiate your quote?

Comment: No,stability is determined by checking if the eigen values have -ve real part. In general, 2nd order system will have 2 eigen values which can make the system stable/unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then why do we say a second order LTI system has only 2 eigen
>   values/vectors?"

Consider the following 2nd order system:

$$a\ddot y(t) + b\dot y(t) + cy(t) = x(t)$$

We can write this as

$$\mathbf Dy(t) = x(t) $$

where \$\mathbf D\$ is the 2nd order *operator*

$$\mathbf D = a\frac{d^2}{dt^2} + b\frac{d}{dt} + c$$

We know that \$e^{st}\$ is an eigenfunction of the operator \$\mathbf D\$ with eigenvalue \$\lambda = as^2 + bs + c\$

$$\mathbf De^{st} = \lambda e^{st} = (as^2 + bs + c)e^{st}$$

thus there are an infinity of independent eigenfunctions for this linear time invariant differential *operator*.

Next, consider the *equation*

$$\mathbf Dy(t) = 0$$

Now we have a constraint - we seek the specific eigenfunction(s) with eigenvalue \$\lambda =0\$.

As is well known, we proceed as follows:

$$\lambda = as^2 + bs + c = 0$$

which has *two* independent solutions

$$s = s_{0\pm} = -\frac{b}{2a} \pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{(2a)^2} - \frac{c}{a}}$$

These particular eigenfunctions are clearly *special* in that they are the modes of the system - the form of the system output when there is no input.

Comment: shouldn't the eigen value be 1/\$\lambda\$? After all , output y(t) is 1/\$\lambda\$ times input e^st.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion arises because of the different uses of the concept *eigenvalues* in control theory and in signal and system theory. In control theory I've come across the use of *eigenvalues* for the poles of a transfer function. This is why if used with this meaning a second order system has only two eigenvalues (poles). On the other hand, in signal and system theory, the eigenfunctions and corresponding eigenvalues are defined by the response of an LTI system to the input signal \$x(t)=e^{s_0t}\$, with \$s=\sigma+j\omega\$, which is given by

$$y(t)=H(s_0)e^{s_0t}$$

where \$H(s)\$ is the system's transfer function, i.e. the Laplace transform of its impulse response. In this context, \$H(s_0)\$ is called the system's eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenfunction \$e^{s_0t}\$. In this sense, there are of course infinitely many eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.